# ckeditor to resize with div

Tags: jquery, ckeditor, rich-text-editor

I have a div that occupies part of the browser window.  I need the ckeditor to seamlessly fill the div.  When the div resizes, ckeditor should also resize with it.  I'm using ckeditor with jquery.  How can this be accomplished?

If this cannot be accomplished, is there any other rich text editor (like tinymce) which can achieve the desired effect?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I have not found an auto resize built into ckeditor, but its fairly easy to update it.

See this example:
http://jsfiddle.net/lathan/mxuNz/